# Ошибка в реализации алгоритма сортировки пузырьком

Tags: c++, сортировка

В каком месте ошибка?

```
#include "stdafx.h"    
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main() {

    int i, c;
    bool flag;
    int a[10] = { 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1 };

    do {
        flag = false;
        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
                flag = true;
                c = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i + 1];
                a[i + 1] = c;
            }
        }    
    } while (flag == true);

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В последнем цикле выводится `a[i]`, а нужно выводить `a[j]`.

**UPD**

Код, отредактированный с использованием одного из guideline:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()  
{  
    int a[10] = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1};

    bool flag;
    do
    {  
        flag = false;  
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] > a[i + 1])
            {  
                flag = true;
                int tmp = a[i];  
                a[i] = a[i + 1];  
                a[i + 1] = tmp;
            }   
        }
    } while(flag);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;  
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @SnowSnow, не забудьте принять ответ.